# ¿redonde de numero extra grandes?

Tags: java

buenas estoy queriendo realizar una operacion entre un numero super grande "73789622.83"-0.0, el problema va cuando ago esta operacion, el resultado me da "7.378962283E7" como podria darle un formato mas amigable

Comment: Puedes usar el tipo de dato **long** que tiene como valor máximo **9223372036854775807**

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que deseas se suele utilizar la clase `java.text.DecimalFormat`. Esta tiene muchísimas opciones para formatear números y para parsear números formateados. Te muestro un ejemplo utilizando un patrón para formatear un número decimal.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(4589659856658.9865));
```

La salida sería la siguiente:

```
4,589,659,856,658.99
```

Espero poder ayudarte, pero te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a esta clase para que veas las diferentes opciones que tiene.